# Php function calling

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
public function getCode($secret, $timeSlice = null)
{
    if ($timeSlice === null) {
        $timeSlice = floor(time() / 30);
    }

    $secretkey = $this->_base32Decode($secret);

    // Pack time into binary string
    $time = chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).pack('N*', $timeSlice);
    // Hash it with users secret key
    $hm = hash_hmac('SHA1', $time, $secretkey, true);
    // Use last nipple of result as index/offset
    $offset = ord(substr($hm, -1)) & 0x0F;
    // grab 4 bytes of the result
    $hashpart = substr($hm, $offset, 4);

    // Unpak binary value
    $value = unpack('N', $hashpart);
    $value = $value[1];
    // Only 32 bits
    $value = $value & 0x7FFFFFFF;

    $modulo = pow(10, $this->_codeLength);

    return str_pad($value % $modulo, $this->_codeLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

that give me the 2FA code from the secret,
but I don't know how to call the function on another page and how to config the `$timeslice` parameter. Thank you :)

Comment: Is this function part of a class ( from the fact you have `public function`)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the function from a different file you need to [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the file before you can initiate the call.
After which you can call the function (assuming you want 300 in your $timeSlice variable) like :

```
require 'functions_file.php';
$The_code = getCode("this is a secret", 300);
```

If the function is part of a class, you have to either instantiate the class like (assuming the class is named `FunctionClass`) :

```
require 'functions_file.php';
$Instantiated_Class = new FunctionClass();
$The_code = $Instantiated_Class->getCode("this is a secret", 300);
```

Or you can do :

```
require 'functions_file.php';
$The_code = FunctionClass::getCode("this is a secret", 300);
```

Comment: Thanks :) But now I have this error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function getCode() in C:\wamp64\www\test\auth.php on line 5"

Line 5 = "getCode("XU2EXLLZGT6LWXXX", 300);"

Comment: Have you required the correct function file before calling the function? make sure you're attempting to require it from the correct folder if it's not in the same folder as your auth.php file.

Comment: It seems to be a class method (only functions inside a class can have visibility definition). Thus, you should create an instance of that class in order to call the `getCode` function.

Comment: I edited the response in case the function is part of a class as Gabriel mentioned.